# Seaborn pairplots with continuous hues?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, visualization

How may I introduce a continuous hue to my seaborn pairplots?

I am passing in a pandas data frame `train_df` in order to visualise the relationship between the multiple features.

However I'd also like to add a hue which would use their corresponding target values, `target_df`. These target values are on a continuous scale (~ floats between 10 and 100).

I have defined a `sns.color_palette("RdGr")` that I'd like to use.

Right now I have following pairplot (with no hue):

```
sns.pairplot(train_df)
```

How can I pass in the target_df as a hue using color palette defined above?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I would like to help however, I am not quite sure I understand what you trying to archieve. You have two separate datasets. How does one observation from train_df relate to target_df? Also it would be really beneficial to provide an [mre] or simulated data to clarify what your goal is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just assign the `target_df` as a column in `train_df` and pass it as `hue`:

```
sns.pairplot(data=train_df.assign(target=target_df, 
                                  hue='target')
```

However, this will be extremely slow if your `target` is continuous. Instead, you can do a double `for` loop:

```
num_features = len(train_df.columns)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(num_features, num_features, figsize=(10,10))
for i in train_df.columns:
    for j in train_df.columns:
        if i==j:    # diagonal
            sns.distplot(train_df[0], kde=False, ax=ax[i][j])
        else:       # off diagonal
            sns.scatterplot(x=train_df[i],y=train_df[j], 
                            ax=ax[i][j], hue=target_df, palette='BrBG',
                            legend=False)
```

Which gives you something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`pairplot` (well, the underlying `PairGrid`) now delegates `hue` to the mapped function if it supports it. You'll probably *not* want to draw a distinct marginal density for each price, though:

```
diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
sns.pairplot(
    diamonds,
    hue="price", vars=["carat", "depth", "table"], 
    diag_kws=dict(color=".2", hue=None)
)
```

Old answer, useful for demonstrating more flexible use of `PairGrid`:

This could be easier than it currently is, but it's not necessary to recreate `PairGrid` yourself.

```
diamonds = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")
g = sns.PairGrid(diamonds, vars=["carat", "depth", "table"])
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, color=".2")
g.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot, hue=diamonds["price"], s=5, linewidth=0)
g.axes[1, -1].legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(.7, .5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have too low of reputation to comment, so I have to provide a separate answer. I modified the selected answer (by Quang Hoang) in two regards.

First, if your columns have names other than the integers corresponding to the subplots grid, then you'll need to distinguish between the indices (here, `i` and `j`) of the columns, which are passed to `train_df[i]`, and those of the subplots, which are passed to `ax=ax[i,j]`.

Second, seaborn's `distplot` is deprecated, so switch that to `histplot`.

```
num_feats = len(train_df.columns)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(num_feats, num_feats, figsize=(10,10))

# In order to assign the plots to the correct axes,
# create a dictionary to refer the column names to integers.
col_dict = dict(zip(train_df.columns, range(len(train_df.columns))))

for col_i in train_df.columns:
    i = col_dict[col_i]
    for col_j in train_df.columns:
        j = col_dict[col_j]
        if col_i==col_j:
            sns.histplot(train_df[col_i], kde=False, ax=ax[i,j])
        else:
            sns.scatterplot(x=train_df[col_i], y=train_df[col_j], ax=ax[i,j], hue=target_df, legend=False)

fig.tight_layout()  # make room for subplot labels
```

Answer (score -2):

In the documentation ( https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html ), you can see that you just need to set `palette = my_palette` when calling the function like so:

`sns.pairplot(train_df, palette = my_palette)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't work as I need to also incorporate information about the continuous target variables in target_df via the hue parameter.

Comment: Try `sns.pairplot(train_df, hue= my_palette)`